# Protractor download image file without clicking on link

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I'm trying to compare two logo images.
The test case is basically

- dowload image A into dir
- compare image A with image B (already present in folder)

All guides and questions point out how to download a file when there's a link for doing such thing. But in this case the I want to download an image knowing its URL only.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
a.href = uri; // Set the uri.
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
delete a;
```

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = '58832_300x300';
a.href = 'https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300';
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
delete a;
```

Comment: Protractor doesn't like 'delete a' and even removing it throws an error 'Failed: document is not defined'